# SwiftUI Crash LayoutComputer.EngineDelegate.sizeThatFits?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, crash

I can't identify the source of this crash, and when I "Open in Project" Xcode doesn't point to any particular area of my code.  What could be causing this?  It seems to be when a certain button is tapped.

[image]

Comment: Probably a SwiftUI bug. If you can reduce the code into a minimal example which still causes the crash, that would be useful for us to help debug it.

Comment: Thanks but its a huge app and that's my problem I can't even tell the process or the file its happening in.

Comment: It's hard to find the issue, but I can point you towards [this tweet](https://twitter.com/steipete/status/1386323251530330114) from today. It may be relevant or the same bug as you have. It may not be helpful, but it is difficult to debug something like this without being able to reduce the code down.

Comment: Thanks yes I agree, not much to go on with this stack trace

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

After I ran into this same sort of problem, the solution for me, was to clean my build folder, then perform a **full** build of my application for my target device, as opposed to *not* cleaning my build folder, and just performing an *incremental* build of my app.

## Steps I followed to trigger this bug, and to resolve my issue

1. I had an Xcode Project, containing:

   1. A Swift Package I'd added as a "Local Swift Package" which contained:

      A module that defined a public method (let's call it `modifyListRow`) in an extension of the `View` protocol.
   2. My SwiftUI Application for iOS which contained:

      My `@main App` which rendered a SwiftUI View that contained:

      ```
       List { ForEach { MyRow.modifyListRow() } }
      ```
2. I then did a **full** build & run of my app - which depended on that Local Swift Package, and after the app launched on my physical iPhone X device, I saw that everything worked properly.
3. I then modified the body of the `modifyListRow` method, in such a way that it would affect how the sizes of the List-rows produced by the `ForEach` View should be calculated by the SwiftUI Framework.
4. I then did an **incremental** build and run of my app.
5. This time, after my app launched on my iPhone, I just saw a blank screen in it because SwiftUI had failed to render any of my app's views, and I saw in Xcode that my app had crashed while attempting to calculate a `sizeThatFits` for a view - presumably for one of the List-rows produced by my `ForEach` View.
6. I then cleaned my build folder, and did a **full** build & run of my project, and after the app launched on my iPhone, I saw that this time everything worked properly.

## Hypothesis of cause of bug for my app

Presumably, Xcode had cached the compiled code for my SwiftUI View that contained the List after I did the first **full** build, but didn't invalidate the compiled code for that View, despite the fact I'd modified the body of the `modifyListRow` method in such a way that the List-rows would have needed to have their sizes calculated differently by the SwiftUI Framework. This made it so that my SwiftUI View would not be re-compiled during the **incremental** build I'd performed, despite the fact the `modifyListRow` method **was** re-compiled. Consequently, the compiled code of my SwiftUI View and the `modifyListRow` method became "out-of-sync" in the build artefact, and hence, the SwiftUI framework failed to calculate the sizes of the List-rows. But cleaning my build folder, and performing a full-build, made it so that my SwiftUI View would be re-compiled, along with the `modifyListRow` method, and hence, the compiled code for my SwiftUI View **and** the `modifyListRow` method resumed being "in-sync" in the build artefact just as they originally had been. This made it so that the SwiftUI Framework would be able to successfully calculate the sizes of the List-rows.

But please remember, this is just my **hypothesis** as to the cause of the bug for my app - it may be incorrect.